# SQL sum based on ID and time interval

Tags: sql, sum

I need to calculate values based on 24-hr time interval, from 7am to 7am the next day for the same ID.
For example, one of the patient record is:

```
ID entrytime         value 
p1 2020-01-01 7:04    2
p1 2020-01-01 7:04    2
p1 2020-01-01 8:15    3
p1 2020-01-01 21:06   4
p1 2020-01-02 6:05    1
p1 2020-01-02 23:54   2 
p1 2020-01-03 5:21    1
p1 2020-01-03 8:45    1
```

How can I sum it up to have:

```
ID duration                          sum
p1 2020-01-01 7am to 2020-01-02 7am  12
p1 2020-01-02 7am to 2020-01-03 7am  3
p1 2020-01-03 7am to 2020-01-04 7am  1
```

I tried to create a variable duration, but it does not reflect correct time period. On top of that, I have some measures happened at the same time and with the exact same value, the 'group by' function totally omitted the value. In this case, the second(p1 2020-01-01 7:04    2) observation was removed during calculation, giving a wrong sum of 10. My current code is something like this:

```
select sum(value) as sumvalue, t.id, t.Duration 
from (
SELECT 
   cast(p.value as int) as value, 
   p.id,
   Duration = cast(DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, p.entry_time), '07:00:00') AS varchar)+' - ' 
   + cast(DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1,  p.entry_time), '07:00:00') AS varchar) 
   FROM ##temp_value p

    GROUP BY p.id,
     p.entry_time,
     p.value

     ) t
     group by t.id, t.Duration
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can subtract 7 hours, convert to a date, and aggregate:

```
select id,
       dateadd(hour, 7, convert(date, dateadd(hour, -7, entrytime))),
       sum(value)
from ##temp_value p
group by id, convert(date, dateadd(hour, -7, entrytime))
```